# Tracking device path using optimal battery usage

Tags: android, gps, location, location-client

How to track the user by using location client with optimal battery usage(Device has to fetch exact locations using HIGH_ACCURACY mode when moving and switch to BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY mode when he is still at the same location)?

Comment: whats the reason for downvote?